# Getting last entry for each of a distinct column value

Tags: sql, psql

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | type | amount
------------------
1  | red  | 2
2  | blue | 71
3  | red  | 4
4  | blue | 11
5  | red  | 9
6  | blue | 16
```

I'd like to write a query that returns * for the last distinct value of `type`. In this case the last row where the `type` is `blue`, and the last row where the `type` is `red`. So it would return:

```
id | type | amount
------------------
5  | red  | 9
6  | blue | 16
```

How can I do this?

Comment: tag your DBMS please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this in Postgres is using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (type) id, type, amount
from table
order by type, id desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sub-query to find the `max` id for a type and `join` it to the main table.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a289/1)

```
select id, t.type, amount
from (select max(id) as maxid, type from tablename group by type) x
join tablename t on t.id = x.maxid and t.type = x.type
```

Comment: Thank you to the original poster for posing the question and Vamsi for an elegant answer.  Unfortunately Gordon's answer didn't work for me as it returned distinct combinations of all the fields but then maybe Distinct and 'distinct on' work differently..